# Google Cloud Storage - Download EMEA

Tags: google-cloud-storage, stackdriver

I'am new user on GCP-Storage. I have been charged for large downloads to EMEA(region), but my service(API) conects only to Americas.

**Question:**
Would anyone please advise on how to set StackDriver  or other tool to properly monitor storage at CGP egress?

Thanks alot,
Adriano

Answer (score 1):

Stackdriver isn't currently the best tool for this I believe. You should set up a budget and alerts. Just go to `billing` in the menu, then `budget & alerts`. The UI should be self-explanatory.

That's the most important part! Only the budget  set there can definitely safe you from exorbitant bills if someone is trying to ruin you/send spam from your instances etc.

Stackdriver's integration with the billing system is currently rather weak, possibly because it's an outside technology that was aquired. Here's what you can do:

- If you create a chart, set `resource type` to `Pub/Sub Topic` you can choose `Costs of Operations` which shows your costs live (but you can't create alerts on it).
- The GCE metrics include outbound and inbound traffic, so create a chart for that as well.
- In the alerts section, you can add an alert to notify you when your hourly egress crosses a threshold you can define – Or suddenly increases in a way it usually doesn't. Note that it could be hard to avoid false positives. Try to find out the maximum throughput of your instances, calculate how fast you need to be alerted and set these alerts based on that value.
- If you see a sudden, sustained spike in traffic check the logs. Depending on what ports your firewall configuration has opened, you may find the cause in the webserver or sshd logs. (Oh yeah: go to the network settings and disable all ports you don't need).

If that doesn't help, you'll have to leave google and ssh into the machine(s). A tool I've used before and which is quite easy is nethogs.

```
$ sudo apt-get install nethogs
[...]
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nethogs
[...[
Setting up nethogs (0.8.1-0.3) ...

$ sudo nethogs  
TOTAL                                                                       2.873       1.829 KB/sec
NetHogs version 0.8.1

    PID USER     PROGRAM                                           DEV        SENT      RECEIVED
   1975 root     /opt/google-fluentd/embedded/bin/ruby             ens4       0.480       0.999 KB/sec
  23054 root     /usr/bin/python                                   ens4       0.021       0.412 KB/sec
[...]
```

That will show you the process and then, well – it depends on what that is.

Note that one possibility is that you have been hacked and the server(s) are used for spam or porn distribution or whatever. In that case it's possible (or actually to be expected) that **the tools on the server have been patched/replaced to hide the intrusion**. Search for `rootkit detection` if there's a mismatch between the server's internal data and the google tools. If you cannot exclude this possibility with certainty, do not attempt to remove the rootkit. Power down the server(s), create new ones from scratch and, if unavoidable, mount the old disks as read-only partitions in another clean instance to extract the data  with utmost care.

Comment: Many thanks Mattew. Very usefull and quality  information.